# Suggestion in the writing of personal notes on mathematics

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, self-learning, education

I will premit that I'm doing a PhD in partial differential equations (from a functional analysis perspective). I got a degree in mathematical engineering 2 years ago (so not exactly mathematics, in fact I lack of a complete preparation in General Algebra (I only know linear algebra), advanced geometry (differential geometry) and I know very little about topology). However in the meantime I do research in PDE's  I wanted to study and to put togheder all the knowledge that I acquired at the university.

To this purpose I wanted to write some personal notes (in Latex) that start from the very bottom of the things I learned and go to PDE's. In particular I like to go from the very general things to the particular, not the other way aroung (which I consider great for the initial understanding but then very limiting and more time consuming once you have that initial understanding) I thought of something like this:

1. Naive set theory (this will be enough for me)
2. Point-set Topology  (starting from topological space and going throgh all the important topological concepts, e.g. limit points, compactness, continuous functions, that if I looked at them only on $\mathbb R$ or a metric space in general it would be a very limited perspective). In this part also the concept of metric space and metrization would be investigated. For this study I would refer to the introductory book [SIDNEY A. MORRIS, TOPOLOGY WITHOUT TEARS1]
3. Abstract Measure Theory. In this way I would introduce the concepts of measures and of  Lebesgue integrals. I would probably refer to my notes at university.
4. Functional analysis on infinite dimensional vectors spaces  (so I will miss analysis on metric spaces, but that's ok for my purposes). Here I would start from Vector spaces and I would go to normed space (leaving out seminorms, local convexity for which I would only refer to books), Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces. Unbounded operators and adjoints would be introduced. In this part Distributions and Sobolev spaces are introduced. I would refer to [Peter Lax, Functional analysis].
5. Semigroups of linear operators and applications to PDE's, reaching my goal.

In all of this the things that I give for granted are basic calculus on Real (or complex) spaces, so that when introducing the abstract concepts I have in mind that these are some generalizations of the ones in $\mathbb R^n$.

I plan to write a first "quick" edition in 1 year where most proofs are omitted for the sake of time (but I will refer to precise theorems to specialized books), because this notes will permit me to organize the ideas in my mind with a bottom up structure, so at first I'm not interested in writing down proofs. Then in future I will probably complete the missing proofs (and wriring them in a way that I really understand them).

What do you think? Am I missing something or do you have any suggestion? Or do you know someone that wrote something similar, that I can find online, so that I can take inspiration from that?

Comment: If you’re doing a PhD, use your time more wisely, on research. We all tend to procrastinate, but really, focus on the research.

Comment: For a PhD in PDEs it sounds way too fundamentalistic to write personal notes on naive set theory tbh. TL;DR. Generally this is not a bad idea but needs limitations. Most work in a PhD requires getting to know the relevant literature of your specific problem plus full immersion of your mind into making your own contribution.

Comment: Yeah, of course the main focus is research. But I always dedicated some time on self-study (also in the evening). So I will write them during the evening if I'm at home, I usually do research in the day. I think that this will really boost my understanding of mathematics and then my research will benefit.

Comment: That's fine. Later in life you will realize that most books and lecture notes started as somebody's personal notes.

Comment: Yeah, sure.. I need to know very well semigroup theory in my phd. So functional analysis is essential. Topology and naive set theory are there becase I need some general understanding of the concepts (but without knowing the very details of the proofs)

Comment: If you really want to write such a book, which is a great idea in my mind, do yourself a favor and write the concept top-bottom first. If you follow your points 1-2-3-4-5 you will get lost. Start with your examples, SIR models maybe for obvious reasons, and write down what you need for it. Then write down what you need for the keywords you've written down etc. If you start with sets and start climbing, you will be forced to come back and add little lemmata all the time. The roadmap is the key. It guarantees that you haven't forgotten something and that you will not end up writing four books.

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion, thanks @MariusS.L.

Comment: However does that structure make sense or something must be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend *taking a good, rigorous course* on each of these low-level ideas at some point (or maybe you already have for some/all of them). This will automatically result in creation of some amount of notes, old homework assignments, etc which you could reference later if needed. It will also just force you to practice with the relevant concepts. I think it's important to have a "$\ge$ reasonably solid" understanding of the foundations of your area.

However, your suggestion here sounds closer to *writing shortish textbooks* on each of these low-level areas. I think this is much more investment than required to do your PhD work well. In my PhD program I did see a few people write out very extensive documents like this, but I would only recommend it as a fun/interesting side project. Which is not a bad thing - successful math students are usually the ones who just really enjoy math and often find themselves studying/learning extra math stuff on the side! But you should understand that this project is not your main priority, and don't let it get in the way of your main tasks.

Source: finished my math PhD at UCLA in 2017; spent a bunch of time around math grad students both before and after that.

Comment: Yes of course that is not the priority. The priority is research. But thanks for the suggestions.